# Excel If cell is not blank, copy row into sheet2

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, macros

I was trying to figure out how to have excel look at a cell in my workbook, if the cell has a value greater than 0 then copy that row into sheet2. It then looks at the next cell in the column.

Does anyone know??

I need it looking at cell I10 to start off and if I10>0 copy data from A10:K10 to sheet2 else look at I11 and repeat, then I12... until all 750+ rows are either copied or not.

Thanks so much for all the help!!!

Comment: What have you tried? This requirement is so simple. An online Excel VBA tutorial would cover everything you needed to know. This site is for programmers to help one another develop. You say "750+ rows". Look up how to find the last row of a column. You want to look at I10, I11, I12 , ... Innn where nnn is the last row number.  Do you know what a For loop is? Do you know how to access a cell using variables?  The tutorial would teach you all this. A hour or two's study would allow you to solve this problem and the next.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

Dim cell As Range
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long

lastRow = Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
i = 10 ' change this to the wanted starting row in sheet2

For Each cell In Sheets(1).Range("I10:I" & lastRow)
    If cell.Value > 0 Then
        cell.EntireRow.Copy Sheets(2).Cells(i, 1)
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`AutoFilter()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) method of `Range` object and avoid looping through cells:

```
Sub Main()
    With Worksheets("OriginWs") '<--| change "OriginWs" to your actual data worksheet name
        With .Range("I9", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp))
            If IsEmpty(.Cells(1, 1)) Then .Cells(1, 1) = "dummyheader"
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">0"
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then .Offset(1, -8).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 11).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Worksheets("TargetWs").Cells(1, 1) '<--| change "TargetWs" to your actual destination worksheet name
            If .Cells(1, 1).Value = "dummyheader" Then .Cells(1, 1).ClearContents
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

BTW, the statements:

```
If IsEmpty(.Cells(1, 1)) Then .Cells(1, 1) = "dummyheader"
```

and

```
If .Cells(1, 1).Value = "dummyheader" Then .Cells(1, 1).ClearContents
```

can be avoided if your cell I9 has some text for sure

Comment: @TimothyWinkler, did you get through it?